# Ошибка чтения входных данных

Tags: python, eof

IDE выполняет код корректно, но онлайн интерпретатор на курсе выдает ошибку:

> line 6, inp = input() EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Объясните почему так происходит. [onlinegdb](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_interpreter) код тоже успешно выполняет. Обработка исключения с помощью конструкции try - except тоже не помогает, появляется ошибка превышения времени выполнения. Видимо, такое заданием не предусмотрено.
**Задание звучит следующим образом:**

> Необходимо написать программу, которая будет считывать
> последовательности измерений. В каждой последовательности нужно
> выбрать максимальное значение, а в итоге вывести отсортированный по
> убыванию список этих макс значений, разделенных символом “;”. Во
> входных данных в первой строке будет задано целое положительное число
> – сколько записей нужно обработать, причем самих записей может быть
> больше чем это число, это нужно учесть. Значения в рамках одной записи
> разделены пробелом, минимальное число значений в записи – 1. Записи
> разделены переводом строки.

```
num = int(input())
lst, between = [], []
while True:
    inp = input()
    if inp == "":
        break
    else:
        for spin in inp.split():
            between.append(int(spin))
        lst.append(max(between))
        between.clear()
print(*sorted(lst[:num], reverse=True), sep=';')
```

Comment: А на самом курсе есть примеры, как ввод читать? Бывает, что там через `stdin` нужно читать. И добавьте вариант кода, как вы `try-except` добавляли, прерывали ли вы цикл в этом случае?

Comment: Смотря как вы обрабатываете. Скорее всего в except нужно break написать.

Comment: А в целом - лучше учитывайте всё же `num` и не читайте записей больше, чем в нём указано, возможно ошибка из-за этого. Вы полагаете, что в конце будет пустая строка, но откуда вы это взяли? Ориентируйтесь на число строк `num`, а не на пустую строку. Ну и `max` тут проще считается, промежуточный список не нужен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раз уж все стали код писать. Незачем читать лишние строки и потом отрезать их от результата. Читайте ровно столько строк, сколько вам указано во вводе, не читайте лишнего. И не полагайтесь на то, что в конце будет пустая строка. Вот вам однострочник по приколу:

```py
print(*sorted((max(int(spin) for spin in input().split()) for _ in range(int(input()))), reverse=True), sep=';')
```

Comment: Можно попридираться, конечно, что `join` проще `sep`, a `[::-1]` проще `reverse=True`, но не буду.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ, приму к сведению. Ваш код интерпретатор принял.

Comment: Боролись с этим боролись в Perl и вот удар, откуда не ждали. От Python :-)

Comment: @VladimirIgnatenko С чем именно? ))  Я когда-то писал на `Perl`, но это было лет 25 назад ))

Comment: @CrazyElf c однострочниками и трудночитаемым кодом

Comment: @VladimirIgnatenko Ну, тут чисто по приколу )  В промышленном программировании я пишу понятный код )

Comment: @VladimirIgnatenko, а я просто обожаю писать однострочники. Зачем с ними бороться, если умеешь их писать и отлаживать? Питон для этого отлично подходит (хотя Перл и лучше).

Comment: @Глеб однострочники это хорошо до тех пор пока вы это делаете для себя и для прикола. Как только вы начинаете писать код, который надо будет читать другим, то эти другие сразу же помянут вас недобрым словом. Потому что основное правило хорошего кода в том что он пишется не для интерпретатора, а для людей.

Comment: @VladimirIgnatenko, а я только для себя код пишу) Да и в серьёзных программах я ограничиваюсь одним уровнем вложенности, а это вполне читаемо.

Answer (score 2):

Все это делается гораздо проще:

```py
n, *l = open(0)
l = [max(map(int, i.split())) for i in l]
print(';'.join(map(str, sorted(l)))
```

Весь список можно спокойно считать с потока через `open(0)` (он считывает все из stdin до EOF'а как раз), да и остальную работу поместить в две строчки.

Comment: Нужно int без скобок передавать, а то `int() == 0`

Comment: Интересное решение, спасибо

Comment: @Paradise, не забудьте принять помогший вам ответ!

Answer (score 2):

Ответ был получен. Не совсем верно понял задание, а именно

> причем самих записей может быть больше чем это число, это нужно учесть.

отсюда и неправильный алгоритм.
Если изменить мой код следующим образом, то такое решение сработает:

```
num = int(input())
n = 0
while n < num:...
```

Comment: Ну да, вполне возможно, что там в каких-то тест-кейсах 100500 строк, из которых обработать нужно всего 10, вот вам и "ошибка превышения времени выполнения".

Answer (score 1):

Похоже, что в вашем примере, который вы используете для проверки последней стоит пустая строка. И поэтому срабатывает break в проверке

```
if inp == "":
```

А вот на курсе такого нет. И вы пытаетесь читать строку, когда уже достигнут конец файла (потока). О чем и получаете ошибку.

В общем случае правильным было бы добавить еще проверку и на EOF. Но в вашем учебном примере будет достаточно считать число строк - так как вы знаете, сколько их должно всего быть. Да и в условии задачи говорится, что строк в исходных данных может быть больше, чем указано в первой строке. Т.е. если вы не будете это учитывать, то считаете "лишнего" и ваш результат будет неправильным.

Самое простое, это перед чтением проверять что еще нужно считать строку, а при чтении строки вычитать из **num** единицу.

```
if num <= 0:
    break

inp = input()
num = num - 1
#... дальше операции с inp ...
```

Comment: Комментарии не //, а #.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание